# Element API: Get Matrix Content

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi

So I'm trying to get my Matrix as JSON with the [Craft CMS Element API](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api) plugin.

```
<?php

use Craft\elements\Entry;

return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'api/sites' => [
            'elementType' => craft\elements\Entry::class,
            'criteria' => ['section' => 'sites'],
            'elementsPerPage' => 1,
            'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {
                $matrixBlocks =[];
                foreach ($entry->contentMatrix as $block) {
                    switch ($block->type->handle) {
                        case 'sectionTitleBlock':
                            $matrixBlocks[] = [
                                'content' => $block->sectionTitleBlock
                            ];
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return [
                    'matrix' => $matrixBlocks,
                ];
            },
            'paginate' => false,
            'pretty' => true,
        ],
    ]
];
```

The error message im getting is

> "error": {
>       "code": 2,
>       "message": "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"
>     }

I think the problem is that `$entry->contentMatrix` is giving me a MatrixBlockQuery Element.

**$sectionTitleBlock is a normal text field**

Comment: Could you please try the correct syntax `foreach($entry->getFieldValue('contentMatrix')->all() as $block)`? Please make sure all entry types have a field in the layout `contentMatrix`

Comment: Yes. That fixed my problem! Thank you.

May i ask were you got this correct syntax from? I can't find it on the plugins github page.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the plugin, it's just the correct syntax but most people dislike it or don't use that. You should take a look at the source code, you'll see it everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get all related items from a `BaseRelationField` you'll need this syntax

```
$entry->getFieldValue('contentMatrix')->all()
```

Thus your loop will be

```
foreach($entry->getFieldValue('contentMatrix')->all() as $block){
```